# Asp.net Grid View

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my Grid View ,When a button is clicked,i want to insert that row in to database and at the same time make the row invisible in the Grid View.
I can insert in to database but can't make the inserted row invisible.

```
        Dim PayID As Integer = (e.CommandArgument)
        Dim EmpID As Integer = (e.CommandArgument)
        Dim EID As Integer = CType(Dg1.DataKeys(EmpID).Values("EmpID"), Integer)
        Dim PID As Integer = CType(Dg1.DataKeys(PayID).Values("PayID"), Integer)

        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into EmployDetails(EmpID,PayID,PayDate) 
        Values(" & EID & " ," & PID & ",GetDate())"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You might need to bind the GridView to a [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx) instead of a DataSet. Then when you add a row update the DataView to exclude the new row.

Answer (score 1):

After insering your row to db, you should remove the related record from datasource (datatable, dataview) and rebind your gridview.

**EDIT :**

After your Insert operation :

**1.** take your remove the related row from your datasource :

```
Dim insertedRows As DataRow() = myDataTable.Select("ID = " & id)

For Each dr As DataRow In insertedRows

    myDataTable.Rows.Remove(dr)

Next
```

**2.** And after that re-bind your gridview :

```
gridView.DataSource = myDataTable
gridView.DataBind()
```

NOTE : I use a converter to convert codes C# to VB. Hope it's ok.